# In Falling Skies, what happened to Sara?

Tags: falling-skies

This question contains spoilers for Season 5, Episode 3: Hatchlings.

---

When Sara and Pope are out scouting, Sara's legs get stuck in some Espheni goo. She can't get them out, so Pope goes to get help.

> When he gets back, her legs are eaten, but her upper body is fine. How and why did the bugs eat her legs, which were stuck in goo and inaccessible, but not her torso, which was exposed and totally accessible?

This makes no sense to me.